# Vector iterator not dereferencable while implementing quicksort

Tags: c++

I know there are several posts on this problem but I can't seem to fully understand the causes (I'm still a newbie in C++, 3 months experience)
What I'm trying to do is implementing quicksort on a vector of struct (I know there is a built-in qsort function but I want to know how things work tho).
Here is my quicksort code (sort by comparing word.freq):

```
int partition(vector<word> &database, int start, int end) //partition the vector
{
    word pivot = database[end];
    int pIndex = start;
    for (int i = pIndex; i < end; i++)
    {
        if (database[i].freq > pivot.freq)
        {
            iter_swap(database.begin() + pIndex, database.begin() + i);
            pIndex++;
        }
    }
    iter_swap(database.begin() + pIndex, database.end());
    return pIndex;
}
void quickSort(vector<word> &database, int start, int end)
{
    if (start < end)
    {
        int partitionIndex = partition(database, start, end);
        quickSort(database, start, partitionIndex - 1);
        quickSort(database, partitionIndex + 1, end);
    }
}
```

Please anyone clarify faults in my code. All criticisms are appreciated. I want to learn. Thank you.

Comment: Please give us a `main` function.  We don't know if `start` and `end` are valid vector indices.

Comment: "iterator not dereferencable" - is that a compiler error message? If so provide the full text from the compiler and highlight the place in the code involved.  If not, what exactly is your specific problem?  This site is not for code reviews (there is such a site in the StackExchange family, but I can't remember which).

Comment: Note that `database.end()` is not the last element in the data... it's the position one past the end.  Using `iter_swap` with that position is wrong, and you presumably want something bounded by the `end` value passed in.

Comment: @TonyD turns out the site in question is called [codereview.se] - however to be on-topic on that site, OP's code must be working as intended, which isn't the case here.

Comment: It's a debug assertion failure @TonyD

Comment: quickSort(database, 0, database.size()-1);

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie basically i just passed the parameters like the comment above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`end()` does not return an iterator to an element of the vector. It returns an iterator to one element past the last element. So this line is probably the cause of your problem.

```
iter_swap(database.begin() + pIndex, database.end());
```

That tries to swap the element at `database.begin() + pIndex`, with the element at `database.end()`, which is not valid. It will involve a dereference of `database.end()`, which explains why you get the message "iterator not dereferenceable". If you want to swap with the last element, you would do this:

```
iter_swap(database.begin() + pIndex, database.end() - 1);
```

Comment: so you mean it's not that database.end() is valid but just like an index which points to somewhat past the last element?

Comment: @GiaPhatHa: Yes, where "somewhat" = 1.

Comment: thank you, i understand now, i miscomprehend the use of database.end()